# Syncing a music directory with a device when the device doesn't have enough space

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

In my library I have a directory with several inteligent and fixed playlist, which I want to sync my device. The problem is that the size of the directory is too big for my device, but since I can't create a playlist of a playlist to limit the size of the directory, or limit the size of the directory itself, I'm trying to find a way to convince iTunes to fill the device with tracks of the playlist until the device is full, without throwing me several warnings. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a smart playlist, *you can* select another playlist or folder as source, there you can personalize how would the selection of songs be done, etc.